3D AABB vs AABB discrete collision - How to choose resolution axis?
I'm working on a simple 3D collision system that only needs to handle dynamic AABB vs static AABB. It needs a sliding collision response, but it doesn't need to sweep (i.e. doesn't need continuous, discrete is fine).
I've been thinking about the algorithm in 3 steps:

Test for intersection
Determine which axis to resolve along
Determine whether to push in the position or negative direction along that axis

#1 is trivial for AABBs. #3 seems easy, in that you can use the inverse of the velocity's sign, e.g.
Vector3 velocity = /** the dynamic box's velocity */
Vector3 overlap = /** the overlap between the two boxes */
// Assuming we determined to resolve along the X axis
float rejectionX = -std::copysignf(1.0, velocity.x) * overlap.x;

My issue is with #2. I haven't found an approach that both works well in 3D, and seems fairly well fit to my constraints. Here are the approaches I've found:

Calculate the overlap from the previous frame. If it was already overlapping along an axis, you can assume that one of the other axes were the first to collide.

This works well for 2D, but in 3D you end up with multiple cases where you can only rule out 1 axis, and thus need some alternative approach for deciding between the remaining 2.


Calculate the time to collide along each axis, choose the smallest.

This is what the swept approach uses. It would work, but seems more costly than I should need given my constraints.


Calculate the minkowski difference, use that to calculate the penetration vector.

Again, this seems more costly than I should need. Specifically the phase where you're looking for the closest point on the minkowski box's bounds, and you need to test every face to find the minimum distance.


Choose the axis of least (or most) overlap.

These seem to have a lot of edge cases where they don't work well.


Use the inverse of the velocity.

This doesn't produce a reasonable response.



Am I unfairly dismissing any of these approaches? Are there any other approaches that are a better fit for my constraints?

Have you profiled option 2? This does not need to be a particularly expensive calculation, and you can vectorize the three axes to compute the three impact times at once.

I was more trying to avoid all of the branching involved in something like this approach. Getting the overlap between two AABBs is so cheap, I was hoping there was a way to determine a rejection axis without getting into all of the branches. It looks that may be the only way, though.

I suspect the right SIMD instructions could do it with minimal branching — I've done it on GPU but I don't have a reference implementation handy. What tech stack are you using?

I'm building a C++ engine on top of SDL2, targeting windows and linux. This code will be running on clients and on a server (aiming for large player counts, hence the concern about performance).
